# Firebase callable function not receiving arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Implementing a simple function on typescript to call a Firebase callable function is not working.
Using firebase-tools@4.0.3 -g, firebase-functions@2.0.5, firebase@5.3.1

Firebase callable function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

exports.httpsOnCall = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log(data);
  return data;
});
```

It is deployed correctly

Calling the function in webapp:

```
const a = Firebase.functions.httpsCallable("httpsOnCall");
  a.call({ a: 1, b: "testing", c: true }).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Firebase object initialization:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const config = {
  apiKey: "asdasdasd",
  authDomain: "APPNAME.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://APPNAME.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "APPNAME",
  storageBucket: "APPNAME.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "123456"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const Firebase = {
   functions: firebase.functions()
}
```

Log from firebase:

```
null
```

Log from webapp:

```
{data: null}
```

It seems like data is not reaching the httpsOnCall function, even though the context variable is populated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of doing `a.call`, just call the function `a` with the parameters, like this:

```
const a = Firebase.functions.httpsCallable("httpsOnCall");
  a({ a: 1, b: "testing", c: true }).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

See the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for an example.

Comment: Rookie mistake. I saw the call method and immediately thought it was what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
//imports
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/functions");


//call steatment
const a = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('httpsOnCall');
        a({ a: 1, b: "testing", c: true })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        });
```